# Optimizing index on view of joined table in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, query-optimization

I have a join query on 2 tables:

### table1 schema

```
| k | m | y | s | c | h |
```

### table2 schema

```
| k | l | h |
```

### This is my mysql query:

```
SELECT l,m,y,sum(s)
FROM table1 t1
JOIN table2 t2
on t1.h=t2.h
WHERE t1.c = 405 
AND t2.l in (500)
GROUP BY m,y,l;
```

table1 has over 130 million rows and table2 has 1 million rows. I have created indexes on 2 tables like this:

```
CREATE  INDEX idx_temp1 ON table1(h,c);
CREATE  INDEX idx_temp2 ON table2(h,l);
```

The query is still taking a lot of time (more than 10 minutes). My use case wants the query to be executed under a second. Please tell me if there is any optimization that can be done on the query.

PS: I also tried creating partitions on c, but has not helped much in terms of performance.

Comment: Add the explain plan for your SQL.

Comment: can you provide a table schema for it?

Comment: Just drop indexes you've created and create two new one: on c column in table 1 and l column in table2

Comment: @Jack I have it added already

Comment: @maxim but will it not affect the join of 2 tables on 'h'?

Comment: @user3547555 no. with your version of indexes db cannot find fast records with c = 405

Comment: the most important thing here is the number of records with c equal to 405. the rule of thumb is that if more that 10% of records retrived by index it's usually slower that full table scan

Comment: I mean create table code.

Comment: I think your use case is going to require significant hardware improvements - but all the same, try reversing the indexes (so c,h and l,h)

Comment: Did you try using separate indexing on `h`, `c` and `l` instead of compound `(h,c)`, `(h,l)`? Check explain plan to see if indexes are used for `where` part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this query:

```
SELECT t2.l, t1.m, t1.y, sum(t1.s)
FROM table1 t1 JOIN
     table2 t2
     ON t1.h = t2.h
WHERE t1.c = 405 AND t2.l in (500)
GROUP BY t2.l, t1.m, t1.y;
```

I would suggest two indexing strategies.  Assuming that the condition on `t1` is the most restrictive, then try `table1(c, h, m, y, s)` and `table2(h, l)`.

If t2 is the more restrictive, then `table2(l, h)` and `table1(h, c, m, y, s)`.

Note that the aggregation is going to take time, if the `JOIN` returns a significant number of rows.  There may be no way to get subsecond performance on this query.  You may need to resort to a summary table with triggers to update the values.